# Joining 2 "Half" Fields in ArcMap 10.5

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table

I have 2 fields in the same table which represent the same thing but they were unioned from 2 different data sets, lets call them A and B. Lets say there are 50 records in total, of which A has 25 and B has 25, all of which are distinct (ie. no overlap). How do I go about combining these 2 fields into one field. I'm using ArcMap 10.5.

[image: Sample of What I Want]

Comment: Have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252954/concatenating-strings-from-two-fields-using-python-in-arcmap-field-calculator

Comment: @Midavalo I did see that but that's not what I'm looking for... I don't want to concatenate anything I simply want to populate the field with values from either A or B depending on which one even has a value. Please let me know if this is unclear and I'll edit the original question

Comment: The link should work. Do you have None/Null values or empty strings?

Comment: No I don't have any null values but that link does not describe what I'm looking for.

Comment: I can't actually disclose that, but I will make a sample.

Comment: YOur fields are text/string?

Comment: yes they're text, sorry my example has numbers

Answer (score 1):

Use Calculate Field / Field Calculator with python parser to calculate a third field: `!fieldA! + !fieldB`!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use code you could use the field calculator with selections or definition query.

1. Open the table
2. Select by attribute/definition query where `Field1 IS NOT NULL`
3. Field calculate field desiredresult = Field1
4. Clear you selection query/definition query
5. Add a new selection/definition query where `Field2 IS NOT NULL`
6. Field calculate field desiredresult = Field2